# TCP traceroute works fine but not UDP

Tags: unix, ping, networking

So I ran into this issue where doing

`traceroute some-server.abc.com`

returned `***` for multiple lines and finally reached maximum hops limit.

Doing a `traceroute -T some-server.abc.com` works perfectly fine. I checked the man pages and by default `traceroute` uses UDP protocol and -T forces it to use TCP probe packets.

What can be the possible reasons for such behaviour.
Also note that `ping` works fine with this host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from [traceroute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute#Implementation) Wikipedia page:

> On Unix-like operating systems, the traceroute utility uses User
>   Datagram Protocol (UDP) datagrams by default, with destination port
>   numbers ranging from 33434 to 33534. The traceroute utility usually
>   has an option to instead use ICMP Echo Request (type 8) packets, like
>   the Windows tracert utility does, or to use TCP SYN packets.[1][2] If
>   a network has a firewall and operates both Windows and Unix-like
>   systems, more than one protocol must be enabled inbound through the
>   firewall for traceroute to work and receive replies.

Most likely reason why `traceroute` UDP packets are not getting through is firewall.

Comment: There was a critical typo in the question. I intended to write `note` instead of `not`. I think it impacts the answer.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Also can it be the case that an ICMP Time exceeded messages is not configured for UDP packets? To paraphrase: If UDP packets with TTL 0 reaches the server, it just drops them without returning anything.

Comment: If the host you are trying to reach is on the same network, then this might be the case. Otherwise, I would say it's firewall on your own machine or on default gateway getting in the way.

Comment: its in the same network. Also I am passing the default gateway. The only difference between `traceroute -T` and `traceroute` is the last hop i.e the one to the destination.